# in android how to recycle message after sending it to another thread

Tags: android

I am creating two threads A and B both are ofcourse `non-GUI threads`.
A wants to send message to thread B. 
A has the handler reference of thread B.
When A has called `handler.sendMessage(msg)`. Should it be the responsibility of A to call recyle on it ?

Or should the thread B in the `handleMessage()` after unpacking the msg, call recyle on it ?

I have taken a look at the documents but its not so clear..

Thread B looks like this

```
class B extends Thread {

  public Handler mHandler;

  public Handler getHandler()
  {
      return mHandler;
  }

  public void run() {
      Looper.prepare();

      mHandler = new Handler() {
          public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
              // process incoming messages here
          }
      };

      Looper.loop();
  }
```

}

Thread A sends message to thread B like this

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putString("message", "hello world");
msg.setData(b);
msThread.getHandler().sendMessage(msg);
```